Where can i find the eccodes's default definitions and samples on Windows?
I installed eccodes using anaconda on Windows 10 platform, but now I can't find its default definitions and samples, where to find them please?
My anaconda installation path is D:\anaconda3.
The eccodes installation command used is conda install -c conda-forge eccodes.
BTW:
I installed it on linux platform using the same command and the default paths can be looked up through codes_info, after I copied these files to windows and set environment variables, viewing the files using grib_ls prompts the following error:
ECCODES ERROR   :  Unable to get startStep as double (Key/value not found)
I hope someone can help me find these files
